# How to use Jetty Quickstart with maven-jetty-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I've used the documentation on http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/quickstart-webapp.html to get jetty running using the quickstart mechanism. However, this feature is not very well documented and therefore I could not get it running.

The Documentation states that a `WEB-INF/quickstart-web.xml` will be generated, as soon as `jetty-quickstart` dependency is added, which is not the case.

How to enable jetty quickstart when using the maven jetty plugin?

Comment: What exactly is your error/problem ?

Comment: I've updated the question. It simply seems like the mechanism is not working at all.

Comment: Which command are you executing?

Comment: `mvn install jetty:run`

Comment: To me it seems that the quickstart-mechanism is a one-time process, done before application delivery. It seems to be intended to shorten application startup time. The `java -cp jetty-all-9.3.1-SNAPSHOT-uber.jar org.eclipse.jetty.quickstart.PreconfigureQuickStartWar myapp.war` command generates a `quickstart-web.xml` that contains more information and therefore shortens startup process.

Comment: I'am aware of that. But the documentation states that this can be integrated at build time - which is exactly what I am trying to do. '" In a maven project this is done just by adding a dependency on the artifact ID jetty-quickstart..."'

Comment: And your webapp is an instance of `org.eclipse.jetty.quickstart.QuickStartWebApp ` ?

Comment: Yes it is. Copied the "myapp.xml" from the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In the jetty-plugin documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html) it is stated in the chapter *jetty:effective-web-xml* that

> Quickstart is not appropriate for the mvn jetty goals